# Android DiagonalLayout java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path must be convex

Tags: android, emulation

I've created my app using DiagonalLayout. (https://github.com/florent37/DiagonalLayout)

I'm really confused by this, because on real devices it's working properly, but on emulator when I set the following param: app:diagonal_angle="10" my app crashes and got the following error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path must be convex

Any thoughts why this is?

stack trace:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path must be convex
>       at android.graphics.Outline.setConvexPath(Outline.java:216)
>       at com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout$1.getOutline(DiagonalLayout.java:151)
>       at android.view.View.rebuildOutline(View.java:11227)
>       at android.view.View.invalidateOutline(View.java:11200)
>       at android.view.View.setOutlineProvider(View.java:11181)
>       at com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout.calculateLayout(DiagonalLayout.java:76)
>       at com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout.onLayout(DiagonalLayout.java:186)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
>       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)